# PHP Include Directory

Tags: php, include, directory

I am calling `socialmedia.php` from every page on my website to display a little "Social Media" *div* where people can visit my social media pages.

I am calling this using `<?php include './socialmedia.php' ?>` or `<?php include './socialmedia.php' ?>` depending on what directory I am in.

In my `socialmedia.php` file I have the following code.

```
    <a href="http://twitter.com/kinghenryharris" target="_blank">
        <img class="socialMedia" src="../images/twitter_logo.png" alt="Twitter" width="40px" height="40px"></br>
    </a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com/kinghenryharris" target="_blank">
        <img class="socialMedia" src="../images/facebook_logo.png" alt="Facebook" width="40px" height="40px"></br>
    </a>
    <a href="http://youtube.com/mrgorillalogic" target="_blank">
        <img class="socialMedia" src="../images/youtube_logo.png" alt="Youtube" width="40px" height="40px"></br>
    </a>
```

Is it bad practice if I am in the home directory to do `../images/youtube_logo.png`

When calling it from `www.example.com/page.php` does it matter that I am `going up two directories` with ../images/youtube_logo.png`

It seems to work but I am wondering if this is wrong or I should change it so if I am in the home directory do `./images/youtube_logo.png` or should I just leave it the same?

-Henry

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to use absolute paths: `/images/youtube_logo.png`.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Oh duh! And that will set it to the "starting" directory plus /images/youtube_logo.png?

Comment: If by "starting" you mean the root directory (that would be the one where `page.php` exists in your example), then yes.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Sorry, I am very new to programming and php/html.